# ExtJS : How to position Grid Panels

Tags: extjs

I have been trying for a quite a while to place multiple Ext.grid.Panel(s) on a single screen. I want to place them in certain positions. But somehow either they are relatively getting inclined, or overlapping or sometimes I don't see one of the panels at all. I tried with various things like layout:column, layout:absolute etc.

Please suggest how can I position my grids on a single page. I am trying to place 4 Grid Panels in two rows with decent space between each grid.Panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function(){

    new Ext.container.Viewport({
        layout: 'absolute',
        defaults: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'Grid1',
            x: 20,
            y: 20,
        }, {
            title: 'Grid2',
            x: 300,
            y: 20
        }, {
            title: 'Grid3',
            x: 20,
            y: 700
        }, {
            title: 'Grid4',
            x: 500,
            y: 800
        }]
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you Evan. I copy pasted your sample code to see the behavior. I could see 4 Grids with Grid 1 and Grid 3 stuck to the left wall of the screen. So, I tried playing with Grid 1 like this - 

    items: [makeGrid({
        title: 'Grid 1',
        margin: '20 20 20 20'
    })

What I saw is that the Grid 1 shrinks on top, left and bottom too. May be that's becoz those 4 parameters are considered as top, right, bottom and left. However, what I am trying to achieve is if I can place my Ext.grid.Panels ( which i already have ) at four different selected places on the screen. Any help on that?

Comment: I answered your original question. If that question isn't correct then update the original.

Comment: Evan, like I said in my original question 'I want to place them in certain positions.' If I change the margin values in the sample code that you provided, the grid panels are getting resized instead of being placed at a particular co-ordinate or location. Or may be I am not able to modify your sample code as per my needs !

Comment: Or to be more clear, I want my grids in the following positions:
Grid 1: 20px from left and 20px from top, 
Grid 2: 300px from left and 20px from top,
Grid 3: 20px from left 700px from top,
Grid 4: 500px from leeft and 800px from top.

Can you suggest how I can achieve this using your sample code?

Comment: Ahh so it's absolute and (x,y) co-ordinates. Thanks Evan. I am going to try this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Evan, would you mind re-pasting your old code as well as a reference?

Comment: I am terribly sorry, but the reason am asking is:

I have four CRUD Grids populated with Data:
var UserGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
...
});

var RoleGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
...
});

var Map = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
...
});

Now I want them placed in different positions like I mentioned earlier. So, I want to be able to refer to my existing Grids in the Viewport. I tried referring to them in items but the Grids are overriding the Viewport configs. I will be trying more while I wait for your reply and shall post here if I am successful.

Comment: Evan, sorry to bother you again. But do you have answer for the my requirement that I explained in my above comment?